# Why does my count run so many time in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, refresh

[My console logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0t25y.png)
In the console I have a console.count() function just below my useEffect() and its being called 12 times. I'm wondering what could possible be refreshing the code so many times

```
const { user } = UserAuth();
    const { id } = useParams()
    const [count, setCount] = useState(() => { return id ? parseInt(id) : 5 })
    const [name, setName] = useState()
    const [img, setImg] = useState()
    const [stats, setStats] = useState()
    const [types, setTypes] = useState()
    const [otherStats, setOtherStats] = useState()
    const [desc, setDesc] = useState()
    const [favoritePokemon, setFavoritePokemon] = useState()
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const location = useLocation()

    useEffect(() => {
        navigate(`/PokemonPage/${count}`)
        fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' + count)
            .then(res => {
                if (res.status >= 400) {
                    return setCount(1)
                }
                return res.json()
            })
            .then(data => {
                setName(data.name)
                setImg(data.sprites.front_default)
                setTypes(data.types)
                setStats(data.stats)
                fetch(data.species.url)
                    .then(res => res.json())
                    .then(speciesData => {
                        setDesc(speciesData.flavor_text_entries[4])
                        setOtherStats({ "height": data.height, "weight": data.weight, "base_happiness": speciesData.base_happiness, "capture_rate": speciesData.capture_rate })
                    })
            })
    }, [count])

    console.count()
```

Does this have anything to do with the numerous states that I have?

Answer (score 0):

The re-renders are due to the large number of `useState` hooks. You are setting everything one by one, which causes so many re-renders. You might want to use an object with all the keys needed and use that as the state.

```
[pkmnData, setpkmnData] = useState({key:value})
```